# Хелп CMake не использует манифест vcpkg

Tags: c++, cmake, imgui, vcpkg

Сделал все в точности как на этом видео, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U1BnzWX194Q&t=782s&ab_channel=Code%2CTech%2CandTutorials, но после создания проекта CMake в Visual Studio 2022 и добавления vcpkg.json файла не запускается установка зависимостей указанных в манифесте:/ Перепробовал уже все что знаю, ничего не понимаю. В отчаянии уже сюда зашел. Файлы и вывод:

vcpkg.json:

```
{
    "name": "CMakeProject1",
    "version": "1.0",
    "dependencies": [ "imgui", "glfw3", "glad" ]
}
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE "C:/dev/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake"
  CACHE STRING "Vcpkg toolchain file")


add_executable (CMakeProject1 "CMakeProject1.cpp" "CMakeProject1.h")

if (CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_GREATER 3.12)
  set_property(TARGET CMakeProject1 PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 20)
endif()
```

Вывод сборки:

```
1> Для конфигурации запущено создание CMake: "x64-debug".
1> Файл цепочки инструментов был изменен (CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE).
1> Параметры среды:
1>     CommandPromptType=Native
1>     DevEnvDir=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\
1>     ExtensionSdkDir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Kits\10\ExtensionSDKs
1>     EXTERNAL_INCLUDE=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\include;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\ATLMFC\include;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\winrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\cppwinrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um
1>     Framework40Version=v4.0
1>     FrameworkDir=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\
1>     FrameworkDIR64=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64
1>     FrameworkVersion=v4.0.30319
1>     FrameworkVersion64=v4.0.30319
1>     IFCPATH=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\ifc\x64
1>     INCLUDE=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\include;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\ATLMFC\include;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\winrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\cppwinrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um
1>     is_x64_arch=true
1>     LIB=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\ATLMFC\lib\x64;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\lib\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\lib\um\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.22621.0\ucrt\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\lib\10.0.22621.0\\um\x64
1>     LIBPATH=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\ATLMFC\lib\x64;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\lib\x64;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\lib\x86\store\references;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\10.0.22621.0;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.22621.0;C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319
1>     NETFXSDKDir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\
1>     Path=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\bin\HostX64\x64;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCPackages;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\bin\Roslyn;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Team Tools\Performance Tools\x64;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Team Tools\Performance Tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools\x64\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.22621.0\\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\\x64;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64;C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\Tools\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Users\Blaskowitz\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Blaskowitz\.dotnet\tools;C:\Users\Blaskowitz\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\CMake\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\Llvm\x64\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\Ninja;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\Linux\bin\ConnectionManagerExe
1>     PROMPT=$P$G
1>     UCRTVersion=10.0.22621.0
1>     UniversalCRTSdkDir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\
1>     VCIDEInstallDir=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\
1>     VCINSTALLDIR=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\
1>     VCToolsInstallDir=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\
1>     VCToolsRedistDir=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Redist\MSVC\14.34.31931\
1>     VCToolsVersion=14.34.31933
1>     VS170COMNTOOLS=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\Tools\
1>     VSCMD_ARG_app_plat=Desktop
1>     VSCMD_ARG_HOST_ARCH=x64
1>     VSCMD_ARG_no_logo=1
1>     VSCMD_ARG_TGT_ARCH=x64
1>     VSCMD_DEBUG=5 
1>     VSCMD_VER=17.4.0
1>     VSINSTALLDIR=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\
1>     VSSDK150INSTALL=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VSSDK
1>     VSSDKINSTALL=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VSSDK
1>     WindowsLibPath=C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\10.0.22621.0;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.22621.0
1>     WindowsSdkBinPath=C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\
1>     WindowsSdkDir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\
1>     WindowsSDKLibVersion=10.0.22621.0\
1>     WindowsSdkVerBinPath=C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.22621.0\
1>     WindowsSDKVersion=10.0.22621.0\
1>     WindowsSDK_ExecutablePath_x64=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools\x64\
1>     WindowsSDK_ExecutablePath_x86=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools\
1>     __DOTNET_ADD_64BIT=1
1>     __DOTNET_PREFERRED_BITNESS=64
1>     __VSCMD_PREINIT_PATH=C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Users\Blaskowitz\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Blaskowitz\.dotnet\tools;C:\Users\Blaskowitz\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\CMake\bin
1>     SystemDrive=C:
1>     ProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)
1>     ProgramW6432=C:\Program Files
1>     PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=AMD64 Family 23 Model 104 Stepping 1, AuthenticAMD
1>     TMP=C:\Users\BLASKO~1\AppData\Local\Temp
1>     PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=AMD64
1>     ThreadedWaitDialogDpiContext=-4
1>     PkgDefApplicationConfigFile=C:\Users\Blaskowitz\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\17.0_c504a264\devenv.exe.config
1>     PROCESSOR_REVISION=6801
1>     ServiceHubLogSessionKey=3F723268
1>     FPS_BROWSER_APP_PROFILE_STRING=Internet Explorer
1>     FPS_BROWSER_USER_PROFILE_STRING=Default
1>     LOGONSERVER=\\DESKTOP-R8GHRBA
1>     TEMP=C:\Users\BLASKO~1\AppData\Local\Temp
1>     USERNAME=Blaskowitz
1>     SystemRoot=C:\Windows
1>     VSSKUEDITION=Community
1>     VSLS_SESSION_KEEPALIVE_INTERVAL=0
1>     OneDrive=C:\Users\Blaskowitz\OneDrive
1>     CommonProgramFiles=C:\Program Files\Common Files
1>     ProgramData=C:\ProgramData
1>     VSAPPIDDIR=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\
1>     HOMEPATH=\Users\Blaskowitz
1>     OneDriveConsumer=C:\Users\Blaskowitz\OneDrive
1>     COMPUTERNAME=DESKTOP-R8GHRBA
1>     CommonProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
1>     ALLUSERSPROFILE=C:\ProgramData
1>     CommonProgramW6432=C:\Program Files\Common Files
1>     VisualStudioEdition=Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022
1>     VisualStudioDir=C:\Users\Blaskowitz\Documents\Visual Studio 2022
1>     SESSIONNAME=Console
1>     DriverData=C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\DriverData
1>     HOMEDRIVE=C:
1>     windir=C:\Windows
1>     NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS=12
1>     OS=Windows_NT
1>     ProgramFiles=C:\Program Files
1>     ComSpec=C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
1>     PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
1>     VSLANG=1049
1>     VS140COMNTOOLS=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools\
1>     PSModulePath=C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules
1>     APPDATA=C:\Users\Blaskowitz\AppData\Roaming
1>     USERDOMAIN=DESKTOP-R8GHRBA
1>     PROCESSOR_LEVEL=23
1>     USERPROFILE=C:\Users\Blaskowitz
1>     LOCALAPPDATA=C:\Users\Blaskowitz\AppData\Local
1>     VisualStudioVersion=17.0
1>     USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE=DESKTOP-R8GHRBA
1>     PUBLIC=C:\Users\Public
1>     VSAPPIDNAME=devenv.exe
1>     MSBuildLoadMicrosoftTargetsReadOnly=true
1> Командная строка: "C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe" /c "%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\chcp.com 65001 >NUL && "C:\PROGRAM FILES\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2022\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\CMAKE\CMake\bin\cmake.exe"  -G "Ninja"  -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:STRING="cl.exe" -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:STRING="cl.exe" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING="Debug" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH="C:/Users/Blaskowitz/source/repos/CMakeProject1/out/install/x64-debug"  -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM="C:\PROGRAM FILES\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2022\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\CMAKE\Ninja\ninja.exe" "C:\Users\Blaskowitz\source\repos\CMakeProject1" 2>&1"
1> Рабочий каталог: C:/Users/Blaskowitz/source/repos/CMakeProject1/out/build/x64-debug
1> [CMake] -- Configuring done
1> [CMake] -- Generating done
1> [CMake] -- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/Blaskowitz/source/repos/CMakeProject1/out/build/x64-debug
1> Извлеченные переменные CMake.
1> Извлеченные исходные файлы и заголовки.
1> Извлеченная модель кода.
1> Извлеченные конфигурации цепочек инструментов.
1> Извлеченные данные включают пути.
1> Создание CMake завершено.
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: Исправил, больше нет картинок